# How to test high voltage Zener Diodes with multimeter?

Tags: zener, voltmeter

Given an unknown Zener Diode taken from a circuit board, is it possible to measure the Zener Voltage without a datasheet?

I tried to make a circuit like the one below and I add batteries in series till reached 96V. No Zener Voltage met yet. (how to https://youtu.be/WdDFI1IRQds][1](https://youtu.be/WdDFI1IRQds))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUwqN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, you'll have to keep increasing the voltage. A variac would be useful. *Do* check that the diode is conducting in the forward direction with your multimeter just in case!

Comment: Ok. Is it important to know the diode wattage in a circuit also?

Comment: A current source would be easier and safer.

Comment: @Nic1337: Yes you need to limit the current to \$ I_{MAX} = \frac {P}{V} \$.

Comment: And if I replaced an unknown Zener from an unknown board, would be important to know the component wattage also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to measure the conducting voltage of a zener diode. You simply have to have a current limited power supply with a larger voltage than the zener. However, there are a number of precautions to take.

**Personal safety**

Any voltage above the 40v to 50v ballpark is deemed to be no longer touch safe by most authorities. Have everything at high voltage insulated. Use a switch so you can connect and disconnect the zener diode with no power on the clips.

**Power dissipation**

Most small zener diodes, 2mm diameter 10mm long ballpark, will safely dissipate 200mW or so. As you don't know the voltage you're going to get, it's important to limit the power your power source can put into the zener.

The 96v + 1k source you've illustrated in your question can source a maximum power of 2.3 watts into a 48v diode. If you measure the forward voltage, then it will be around 1v, and R1 will be dissipating 10 watts. Is it big enough?

If you use a higher voltage, you will need to redo the sums for power dissipation, and choose larger resistor values accordingly.

Comment: I think your power dissipation math is incorrect. Won't it be ~92 watts?

Comment: @Behrooz on my calculator, 48 x 48 = 2304, which is 2.3 after dividing by 1 k, so that's 2.3 watts in the resistor, and 2.3 watts in the zener, total 4.6 watts. If shorting the output, then the resistor dissipates 96 x 96 / 1000 = 9.2 watts. It's a standard result that a variable load driven by a voltage source through a fixed resistor has maximum power produced in it when at half voltage. At a lower voltage, the voltage is lower, at a higher voltage the current is lower, 2.3 watts is the max dissipated in any voltage zener.

Comment: Yes. I'm an idiot. I read wrong off of the calculator. and was actually going to make this with a much much higher resistor value because I did the rest of the math relative to the 1k resistor here. Thank you.